# What is the difference in my reasoning for sampling with replacement and the correct reasoning?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I am currently reading Blitzen and Hwang's Introduction to Probability book, and am on Theorem 1.4.7, which states that when you are sampling n objects and making k choices from them one at a time with replacement, the number of outcomes is n^k. From my understanding of the explanation, you have a number k different sub-experiments, and there are n different objects that each sub-experiment can be applied on, giving n^k outcomes.

My question is, what is the difference between assigning n different objects onto each choice and assigning each choice onto n objects? for example, if I had n=3 balls and k=2 sub-experiments, then it would be 3 balls to choose from for the first sub-experiment and 3 choices for the second sub-experiment, giving us 3 * 3 = 3^2 = 9 outcomes. However, if I had the same 3 balls, which could have 2 different sub-experiments applied to each, then it would be 2 * 2 * 2 = 2^3 = 8 outcomes. Why is the first reasoning correct, while the second one isn't? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your terms aren't clear...what's a "sub-experiment"? What does it mean to assign a choice onto an object?  To your specific example, if you had $3$ balls (which I'll assume are of three different colors) and you are chosing two of these with replacement (and keeping track of the order of your selections), there are $3^2=9$ ways to do it.  If the colors are $(A,B,C)$, then the nine possible choices are $AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, BC, CA, CB, CC$.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: The book says: "Consider n objects and making k choices from them, one at a time with replacement. Then there are n^k possible outcomes. ...Imagine a jar with n balls, labeled from 1 to n. We sample balls one at a time with replacement, meaning that each time a ball, is chosen, is is returned to the jar. Each sampled ball is a sub-experiment with n possible outcomes, and there are k sub-experiments. Thus, by multiplication rule there are n^k ways to obtain a sample of size k." Does that help with the definitions of the terms? I don't believe the book references them anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The $~2^3~$ computation assumes that each ball has $~2~$ choices for which experiment it will be assigned to.

This assumes (for example)

- that each experiment can be associated with more than one ball,
- that each ball can only be assigned to exactly one experiment.

This is the reverse of the intended operation, which is:

- that ball-1 can be assigned to experiment-1 and also assigned to experiment-2.
- that each experiment must have exactly one ball assigned to it.

Comment: +1 Yes, though an example might help.  The $2^3=8$ cases include ball $1$ assigned to sub-experiment $A$, ball $2$ to sub-experiment $A$ and ball $3$ to sub-experiment $B$, while the $3^2$ cases include ball $2$ assigned to both sub-experiments and the  other two balls not assigned at all.  So they count different types of assignment.

Comment: @Henry Nice example.